# Append to vector as value of hashmap

Tags: vector, rust, hashmap

How does one append to a vector that is a hashmap value?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut dict = HashMap::new();
    let mut prefix = ["", ""];

    let lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum debitis earum quidem dolorem quos consequatur perspiciatis architecto! Reiciendis rem est blanditiis fugiat quidem similique suscipit soluta, ab veniam, laborum numquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum debitis earum quidem dolorem quos consequatur perspiciatis architecto! Reiciendis rem est blanditiis fugiat quidem similique suscipit soluta, ab veniam, laborum numquam.";

    for token in lorem.split_whitespace() {
        if prefix[0] != "" {

            let key = prefix.join(" ");

            if !dict.contains_key(&key) {
                dict.insert(key, vec![token]);
            } else {
                let v = dict.get(&key);
                v.push(token); // does not actually return a vector
            }
        }

        prefix[0] = prefix[1];
        prefix[1] = token;
    }
}
```

The problem is the line `let v = dict.get(&key);` Normally I would expect to be able to push onto the vector, but it seems to be returning some kind of collection, which I'm not sure on how to append to.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### Idiomatic solution

The idiomatic solution to your problem would be to use [entry](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry), as shown below:

```
for token in lorem.split_whitespace() {
    if prefix[0] != "" {

        let key = prefix.join(" ");

        match dict.entry(key) {
            Entry::Vacant(e) => { e.insert(vec![token]); },
            Entry::Occupied(mut e) => { e.get_mut().push(token); }
        }
    }

    prefix[0] = prefix[1];
    prefix[1] = token;
}
```

If the key doesn't exist, you will get a vacant entry that you can use to insert a new value. If it does exist, you will get an occupied entry that you can use to modify the current value. If you want to know more, check out the [documentation](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html).

#### Alternative solution as proposed by Huon in the comments

This one is even shorter and seems better to me once you grasp what is going on:

```
for token in lorem.split_whitespace() {
    if prefix[0] != "" {
        let key = prefix.join(" ");
        dict.entry(key).or_insert(Vec::new()).push(token);
    }

    prefix[0] = prefix[1];
    prefix[1] = token;
}
```

#### Why your code didn't work

`get` returns an `Option<&Vec<&str>>`. You would need to take the `Vec` out of the option, but even in that case you cannot mutate it because it is a shared reference. You can use `get_mut` in combination with `unwrap` as shown below (however, this is considered bad style. You should really use entry):

```
for token in lorem.split_whitespace() {
    if prefix[0] != "" {

        let key = prefix.join(" ");

        if !dict.contains_key(&key) {
            dict.insert(key, vec![token]);
        } else {
            let v = dict.get_mut(&key).unwrap();
            v.push(token);
        }
    }

    prefix[0] = prefix[1];
    prefix[1] = token;
}
```

Comment: A common trick with `Entry`s of `Vec`s is [`or_insert`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert): `dict.entry(key).or_insert(Vec::new()).push(token)`. (`Vec::new()` is very cheap, just storing three constants, so is fine to evaluate unconditionally.)

Comment: Awesome! I edited my answer to account for this alternative

Comment: You can avoid the allocation when not needed by using:

`dict.entry(key).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(token);`

Comment: Note that there is no allocation in either case, since `Vec::new()` doesn't allocate. Rust vectors only allocate when the first element is pushed (or when the capacity is explicitly set without actually pushing)